# Review queue should give me duplicates with low vote count

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Given the new Mjolnir, I have a feature request.

I'd prefer it if when the review queue wants to give me a duplicate on a tag in which I can single handedly vote and close, that it's give me one that doesn't already have 4 votes on it.

The idea is that I can take on the "harder" cases, and leave the "easier" cases to fellow reviewers with no insta dupehammer privileges, so that the close queue can be more meaningfully handled by users with better suited tools.

Answer (score 1):

The queue already doesn't distinguish between cherry pick flags (posts where the next vote will cause action) and any other flag.

Adding such a sort would certainly be non trivial, and that is the essence of this feature request. Why stop at simply preventing cherry pick duplicate flags in tags where you hold a gold badge, and expand it to an actual sort (in addition to the already present filter).

While the filter was arguably a nice step forward, adding a sort would only feel natural. Since the duplicate vote queue is only part of the close vote queue, and since the votes age off, the set of these shouldn't exceed 10,000 ever (or really probably 5,000). As a result, there shouldn't be a performance hit from implementing a sort.

All that said, adding sort to the review queue seems like a heavy lift. I like the idea, but this may in the "nice to have" bucket, as opposed to the "need to have" bucket.